# Decrease top menu so it does not stick out on carousel

Tags: javascript, css, viewport

I have made this website here: http://dijon-egg.com/Possum/

If you click on green big dot button, it takes you to page2.  My problem is I can't figure and fix the menu being too big on page 2 or change view of carousel on page 2 so full carousel can show to us.

Answer (score 0):

As I looked at your source code, I guess you should somehow add the .cbp-af-header-shrink class back to the header, when you click the green button.